# Enumerate related objects through a many-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-views

I know that this question seem to have been answered several times, but none of the answers I found really gave me any pointer to the issue I am facing.

I have 3 models into a django application:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = model.CharField(...)

class Topic(models.Model):
  key = model.CharField(...)

class Interest(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  comment = models.CharField(...)

Person.interests = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through="Interest")
```

The `views.py` is declared as follow:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'index.html'
  context_object_name = 'people_list'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return Person.objects.all()
```

And the `index.html` looks as follow:

```
    {% for person in people_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                {% for interest in person.interests.all %}
                    <li>{{ interest }}</li>
                {% empty %}
                    No interest found
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Surprisingly, the view returns 'No interest found' for every person when the admin site clearly shows interests for all persons.

It looks like the `Person.objects.all()` in the `views.py` did not load the related objects from database.

When using the shell, I get the following results:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app.models import Person, Topic, Interest
>>> person = Person.objects.all()[0]
>>> person.interests
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField>
>>> person.interests.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: Are you using Jinja2 or Django templates? I am asking because you have {% empty %} tag but .j2 extension.

Comment: @marke I did not change the default and renamed to template to (.j2) in order to avoid having VSCode mess with the formatting of the page when saving. Therefore, it's probably Django templates (wrong assumption on my end)...

Comment: @marke Definitely Django templates (`'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'`)

Comment: Ok, I don't know what might be a problem then. Maybe you are using some caching mechanism?

Comment: @marke I did not add any cache (I am still at an early stage)...

Comment: Do persons names appear in the rendered page?

Comment: @marke Yes. The table get generated properly

```
|Name     |Interests              |
|------------|-----------------------|
|Person 1|No interest found|
|Person 2|No interest found|
```

Comment: Not sure but have you tried defining `interests` inside the class definition?

Comment: Why have you set the `Person.interests` field separately, outside the model? That is not how you do it, there's all sorts of metaclass magic in models that only happens during class definition time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define fields within the class definition. This should work:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(...)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField('Topic', through='Interest')
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I got tricked by the order in which I was defining the models. When I initially did as you suggested, I was unable to create the migrations because the Person class was defined _before_ the Topic class. I was getting a name error. BTW, is there a way to tell python not to care about the order of the model definition? I can definitely imagine a case where class A depends on class B, B on C and C on A. It would end into a model that connot be declared.

Comment: If you quote the model name as I did with `'Topic'` above, Django takes care of this.